# Aligned equation environment with number at bottom that allows for page breaking

Tags: equations, align, line-numbering

I'm looking for a better way of using aligned equations in my documents that allows for pagebreaks and numbers only the bottom equation like this:
[image]
Although, I would prefer to be able to have the same sort of numbering as with the aligned environment where you can specify where the number of the equation goes (e.g., \begin{aligned}[c] places the number of the equation at the center of the aligned environment). So far the only solution I've made use of is defining a command that numbers the equation,

```
    \newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
```

and using the align* environment as follows:

```
    \begin{align*}
      \grad^2\phi(\mathbf{r}) &= \frac{1}{r^2}\ud{}{r}\left(r^2\ud{}{r}\right)\frac{Ae^{-r/\lambda}}{r}\\
      &= -\frac{A}{r^2}\ud{}{r}\left(\frac{re^{-r/\lambda}}{\lambda}+e^{-r/\lambda}\right)\\
      &= -\frac{A}{r^2}\left(\frac{e^{-r/\lambda}}{\lambda}-\frac{re^{-r/\lambda}}{\lambda^2}-\frac{e^{-r/\lambda}}{\lambda}\right)\\
      &= \frac{Ae^{-r/\lambda}}{\lambda^2r}.
      \numberthis
    \end{align*}
```

I've tried looking all over the place and so far I haven't found something that does what I want without having to resort to inserting the number manually, which gets bothersome pretty quickly in a long document with a lot of aligned equations. I also tried defining a new environment called aligneq

```
    \newenvironment{aligneq}{\begin{align*}}{\numberthis\end{align*}}
```

which would give me a compile error. Is there already an existing environment that has these capabilities that I just haven't found yet?

Comment: i think what you may be looking for is the `[tbtags]` option to `amsmath` that places the equation number at the last line if the equation numbers are on the right, or at the top line if the numbers are on the left.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: Also remember `amsmath` has `\allowdisplaybreaks`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's clearer to use a numbered display and supress the numbers on lines where you don't want a number.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\def\grad{G}
\def\ud{u}

\def\nl{\notag\\}

\begin{document}

Zzzz

\vspace{35\baselineskip}

zzzzzzz
   \begin{align}
      \grad^2\phi(\mathbf{r}) &= \frac{1}{r^2}\ud{}{r}\left(r^2\ud{}{r}\right)\frac{Ae^{-r/\lambda}}{r}\nl
      &= -\frac{A}{r^2}\ud{}{r}\left(\frac{re^{-r/\lambda}}{\lambda}+e^{-r/\lambda}\right)\nl
      &= -\frac{A}{r^2}\left(\frac{e^{-r/\lambda}}{\lambda}-\frac{re^{-r/\lambda}}{\lambda^2}-\frac{e^{-r/\lambda}}{\lambda}\right)\nl
      &= \frac{Ae^{-r/\lambda}}{\lambda^2r}.
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```